# Ruby on rails app localization by r18n

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, rubygems

I'm install the r18n-rails gem to my app and add migrations to model with locales (:title_en, :title_ua).

After installing this gem I have problems with :label translations.

```
translation missing: ru.default
```

How can r18n gem use i18n yml files?
My yml files are -

`config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', '**', '*.{rb,yml}')]`

Answer (score 0):

For R18n to work well with rails and i18n, you need to set custom load paths with R18n::Loader::Rails

Find more details here - http://rubydoc.info/gems/r18n-rails-api/0.4.9/file/README.rdoc#Rails_Translations

You may have seen this page as well - seems some good instructions here as well - http://r18n.rubyforge.org/

Comment: But after adding I have problem with starting server:

'r18n-core/yaml_loader.rb:42:in `expand_path': can't convert Class into String (TypeError)'

My environment.rb: http://pastie.org/2089192